# Access Google Drive "drive" from terminal?

Tags: terminal, google-apps

I have installed the Google Drive desktop app and it's available on Finder as a mounted drive, but I can't seem to access it from the terminal. For example, when I do `cd 'Google Drive'` I get a `cd: Permission denied: 'Google Drive/'` error. This happens even when I have some files stored locally.

Is there anyway to do this without explicitly downloading the entire Google Drive folder locally?

EDIT: `cd /Volumes/GoogleDrive` produces the same error.

Comment: Where is it mounted?  Somewhere in /Volumes, I imagine.

Comment: Yes, but that produces the same error.

Answer (score 16):

On MacOS, Google Drive is setup as network volume.

When accessing Google Drive from terminal the first time:

```sh
cd ~/Google\ Drive
```

It should pop-up the following:

- MacOS 12.x

  [image]
- MacOS 13.3 and above

  [image]

Click `OK` and you should be able to access it normally.

If for whatever reason pop up not showing, then you have to go into `System Preferences` -> `Privacy & Security`, click on `Files and Folders` and add it manually:

- MacOS 12.x

  [image]

  You need to select(check mark) `Network Volumes`.
- MacOS 13.3 and above

  Picture is showing iTerm. Look for "Terminal" if you using MacOS default app.

  [image]

  In MacOS 13.x, it is changed to `Google Drive`.

  Actual location of `~/Google Drive` is `/Users/<username>/Library/CloudStorage/GoogleDrive-<gmail address>`

Comment: Created account on apple.stackexchange just to say thank you. Very useful answer, I was not able to solve this problem.

Comment: It doesn't work for me. I suspect that there have been additional restrictions since I am running Ventura (13.2.1). It isn't under /Volumes at all.

Comment: @Kramer I updated the answer for MacOS 13.3

Comment: @JohnSiu I appreciate you but I didn't get any popup at all. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @Kramer Try go into System Settings -> Privacy & Security -> Files and Folders, look for "Terminal" and enable "Google Drive".

Comment: @john-siu That did it! Thanks so much.

Answer (score 2):

Google Drive is found in /Volumes/GoogleDrive. Note the lack of the space character in the name. (I have two external drives: iTunes & TMBackup, which show up in the Volumes directory, naturally.)

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned that I tried there too. I get the same exact error when trying `cd /Volumes/GoogleDrive`

Comment: As you can see from the permissions, you don't have access.  As for how Google expects this to work, I can't say.  I kicked Google Drive to the curb when they went to this loopback mount thing, removed the client and everything else, and went back to Dropbox.

Comment: Yes, but I don't know how to give myself permission (and it doesn't make sense since Finder has permission to access it). `chmod` doesn't seem to be working: says `Operation not permitted`. Dropbox is great, but unfortunately the free version limits you to 3 client installations.

Comment: Finder is probably accessing it through whatever extension the application installed.  Not really related, but I have no problem paying for things that actually work.  I was paying for GD too, until they came up with this insane loopback mount concept that just broke things.

Comment: @MarcWilson Finder by default can access network volumes. You can check out my answer.

Comment: @JohnSiu Of course it can.  But a GD volume isn't one.  Unless the extension is installed, in which case you have the bizzarro loopback mount nonsense going on.

Comment: @MarcWilson You are correct that need to install GD to have GD available. But once it is running, the GD is treated as network volume, and apps like terminal need the network volume access permission to read the content. You don't mount GD manually, that is handled by GD software.