# Can't cd in my Google Drive from MacOS with terminal or iTerm2

Tags: terminal, iterm, google-apps

There is a [perfect question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/439714/access-google-drive-drive-from-terminal/442670#442670) for this but I can't comment due to reputation.

I'm using MacOS Sonoma 14.1.1.

If I list my home, I can see:

```
lrwx------    1 [myuser]  staff      88 Oct 11  2021 Google Drive -> /Users/[myuser]/Library/Application Support/Google/DriveFS/[long ID]/my-drive
```

The problem is that if I type "cd Google\ Drive", I get

```
cd: no such file or directory: Google Drive
```

But if I type "cd /Users/[myuser]/Library/Application Support/Google/DriveFS/[long ID]/my-drive", it's successful.

I also checked Settings -> Privacy and Security -> Files and Folders -> iTerm and Google Drive is switched on:

[image]

When I type "cd Goo" and then "tab", autocomplete works, but cd still complains:

```
cd: no such file or directory: Google Drive
```

Any way to enable the symlink, and be able to use it also in shell scripts?

Adding this as requested:

```
% ls -la ~/Library/CloudStorage/
total 32
drwxr-xr-x+   7 [myuser]  staff    224 Oct  6  2022 .
drwx------@ 112 [myuser]  staff   3584 Oct  4 07:12 ..
-rw-r--r--@   1 [myuser]  staff  14340 Jan 16 19:10 .DS_Store
drwx------@  81 [myuser]  staff   2592 Nov 29  2022 Dropbox
dr-x------@   8 [myuser]  staff    256 Jun  5  2023 GoogleDrive-[myemail]
dr-x------    3 [myuser]  staff     96 Jan 20  2023 GoogleDrive-[myemail] (2-6-23 11:12 AM)
drwx------    6 [myuser]  staff    192 Nov 25  2022 GoogleDrive-[myemail] (20-1-23 3:11 PM)
```

btw the proposed answer worked, the following link works:

```
% ln -s /Users/[myuser]/Library/CloudStorage/GoogleDrive-[myemail]/My\ Drive gdrive
```

but I still would like to find out why the other symlink doesn't!

Comment: Non-printing character in the filename? What happens if you type “cd Goog*”.

Comment: If the long `cd` works, it's not an acces right/privacy issue. Does it work if you type `cd Googl`, press TAB to have it auto-complete and then press ENTER?

Comment: Can you change directory if you enter the following: cd "Google Drive" ?

Comment: Your symlink is probably broken.  Try recreating it.

Comment: So, if I type "CD Goo" and then tab, the autocomplete works, but cd still complains:

cd: no such file or directory: Google Drive

Comment: We are getting there, :-) Can you add the result of running `ls -ld ~/Library/CloudStorage/Goole*`? This should give enough details to make this answerable, I'll explain the details in the answer then.

Comment: @nohillside done! see the updated question - btw what are the other two google drive folders found in ~/Library/CloudStorage/ ?

I tried to check their sizes but obviously Google Drive is set in streaming mode so all these folders are all very small.

Comment: Looks like outdated versions of Google Drive. Figuring out what was wrong with the link is difficult even with access to the machine, it‘s hard to do without. Sometimes, restarting from a clean slate is just easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several symbolic links involved here:

- `~/Google Drive` points to `~/Library/Application Support/Google/DriveFS/[long ID]/my-drive`
- `.../my-drive` is itself symlink pointing to `~/Library/CloudStorage/GoogleDrive-EMAIL-ADRESS/My Drive`
- `.../My Drive` is yet another symlink pointing to `~/My Drive` (which contains the actual data)

The easy way to resolve this is to remove the `Google Drive` link and create a new one pointing directly to `~/My Drive`:

```bash
rm ~/Google?Drive
ln -s ~/My\ Drive ~/Google\ Drive
```